# How to use AMD Display Library (ADL) Overdrive State Set function (for overclocking programmatically)

Tags: c#, gpu, ati

I'm using [AMD Display Library](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/graphics-development-sdks/display-library-adl-sdk/) which basically allows us to control certain parameters of the GPU (Clock Speeds / Fan control).

The SDK comes with a `Sample-Managed` code and I was able to get the required result (Core and Memory clock speeds) from `ADL_Overdrive6_StateInfo_Get` method.

Using the `ADL_Overdrive6_State_Set` method (which has the same parameters) returns an error code:

`int od_result = ADL.ADL_Overdrive6_State_Set(OSAdapterInfoData.ADLAdapterInfo[i].AdapterIndex, ADL.ADL_OD6_SETSTATE_PERFORMANCE, stateInfoBuffer);`

-8 `ADL_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED` (Function not supported by the driver.)

I've tested it on a system with AMD Radeon R9 280x / AMD Radeon HD 7970 and a laptop with AMD Radeon 8670M.

Do I need to change something in the driver settings and is there a compatibility issue?

Comment: Can't you ask to the SDK developers? Seems a very specific question.

Comment: I'll try here i guess - http://devgurus.amd.com/welcome

Comment: They don't help much - http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1053325#1053325

Comment: Have you tried confirming that the stateInfoBuffer isn't trying to set some numbers that the driver doesn't allow? Eg you can sometimes only be allowed to set certain things as a multiple of something else. Try setting the GPU to the exact same state its at now to confirm whether your stateInfoBuffer settings are correct.

Comment: @BasitAnwer Were you using 6.0 or 7.0?

Comment: @BasitAnwer I would try 7.0 then, but I'm pretty sure that error means that the function you are trying to use has not been implemented for the combination of GPU and driver you have. Maybe a later driver will adds support, but I doubt there is anything you can do without contacting AMD directly.

Comment: @novaterata Well i moved on to use http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=339656 which uses Afterburner (needs to be installed and running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @novaterata stated in the comment that I could try using the 7.0 library but I moved on to use the Afterburner API
http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=339656

Contacting AMD didn't help.